# jQuery 1.4.2 using .delegate on change of text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue using jQuery 1.4.2 .delegate function with IE 9.  I would love to use the latest version of jQuery and just use the .on function but I am forced to use 1.4.2 due to a vendor product.

My goal is to have a function fire off when the text field changes.  So if it's empty and it gets set to "test" then a function will run.

Here's what I'm trying to do, the alert never shows...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>  
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function test(result) {
                var result = result;
                $("#txtTest").val($("#txtTest").val() + result);
            }

            $("body").delegate("#txtTest", "change",function() {
                alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
            });

        </script>
    </head>  

    <body>
            Test: <input type="text" id="txtTest"/><br />
            <input type=button value=Test name="Submit" id="btnTest" onclick="test('testing the call')" />
    </body>  
</html>
```

I have also tried using myCustomEvent:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>  
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function test(result) {
                var result = result;
                $("#txtTest").val($("#txtTest").val() + result).trigger("myCustomEvent");
            }

            $("body").delegate("#txtTest", "myCustomEvent",function() {
                alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
            });

        </script>
    </head>  

    <body>
            Test: <input type="text" id="txtTest"/><br />
            <input type=button value=Test name="Submit" id="btnTest" onclick="test('testing the call')" />
    </body>  
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I couldn't see that issue here, it fires the change event http://jsbin.com/nutoqomici/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you named your submit button `"Submit"`.  This is a no-no for HTML!!  Browsers default to using internal submit functions when buttons are named submit.  see [*] below.

Also, a `val()` inject doesn't trigger the `change()` event, so we need to call that manually.

Change `Submit` to `xSubmit` and trigger the `change` event at the end of the chain manually and it works.  It should also be in a dom ready wrapper:

html

```
 Test: <input type="text" id="txtTest"/><br />
 <input type="button" value="Test" name="xSubmit" id="btnTest" onclick="test('testing the call')" />
```

js

```
 $(function() {
     $("body").delegate("#txtTest", "change", function() {
              alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
           });
});

function test(result) {
    $("#txtTest").val($("#txtTest").val() + result).change();                     
}
```

demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/at7eoarL/1/

Further Reading:  * - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TAP5-947

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  However, this still doesn't work for me and it doesn't work for me in your jsfiddle example either.  jsfiddle doesn't even appear to support jquery 1.4.2.  Just to clarify, I need that alert to show when "testing the call" is added to the empty text field.

Comment: Correct, JSF doesn't have the old versions as quick selects, however, I have 1.4.2 linked on the left nav as an external resource.   

I understand your question a little more now and will re-work it to show the alert.  Stand by :)

Comment: Ah, okay.  I see the external resource.  Thank you!